# What are these Technic sets with figures?

Tags: technic, set-identification

So I'm trying to identify these two LEGO sets that are rather old. I have long since lost the instructions and I can't seem to find the specific parts on BrickLink. Here are the photos of the complete builds: [Album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1EE8.jpg)

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure if the two belong in the same set (doubt it). But they go together since the teal ship is supposed to fling its plungers to the purple guy's target which activates a spring and launches him out of his ship (and consequently turns off the motor). The purple guy moves around on top of the rubber wheel, which has unfortunately broke. The purple ship takes a 9V battery which powers the motor. I've included a closeup and as you can see the pieces connecting the electronic parts has metal contacts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These builds are both from the same set. [Super Challenge (3038)](http://brickset.com/sets/3038-1/Super-Challenge):

[image: 3038]

Answer (score 2):

This is set [3038/8266 Super Slayer/Super Challenge](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=3038-1#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D), based on the occurrence of the [Technic Figure in Turquoise](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?M=tech013#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D).

[image]